# ISelectionAdapter

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I am trying to mimic the DataGridSelectionAdapter from the Sivlerlight toolkit samples (Autocomplete box) but ISelectionAdapter is not found. I have refs to System.Windows.Controls and the System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Toolkit\Nov09\Bin\System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll).

Anyone know which assembly this is in> MS says it is in S.W.Controls, yet it appears not ( reflector cant seem to locate that interface there either).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN docs for [ISelectionAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.iselectionadapter%28VS.95%29.aspx):-

Namespace:  System.Windows.Controls
Assembly:  System.Windows.Controls.Input (in System.Windows.Controls.Input.dll)

Its not a toolkit provided interface, but you need to add the above SDK provided dll reference to get it.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently my attention to detail is a little low today ;)